# Upload large CSV files in DB with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I created a web page where the user will come in and select a CSV file with (with like 100k rows) and I'll insert that into the database. The thing is, it's taking a long time and this is because (I can't avoid that) I have to read each line which will then go through several loops including some calls to the database. Each line needs to satisfy those requirements (given by my client) before it's inserted into the appropriate table. I could have use the `LOAD DATA INFILE` if I didn't event those 20 requirements for each line so I was wondering if there is a way to make my program run faster. It takes about 5min to insert 8k records which is too slow and I'm stuck with php atm. Anyone has an idea of how I can improve it? I can't post my code here just because it's way too long. 
PS:The import has to be done through a UI

Comment: How can we suggest you anything without knowing anything?

Comment: I expected this to be a common problem so I thought maybe someone would have a general idea?

Comment: I will try to narrow down my code and post it

Comment: Inserting huge CSV should not be a issue at all, but to suggest you some thing I need to know "Each line needs to satisfy those requirements (given by my client)"

Comment: Code is too long to narrow it down. By requirement for instance: If one of the fields is missing skip otherwise check if value of column X is already in the DB if yes attach that record to existing parent otherwise insert it with a new parent (new record in parent table)

Comment: Those are about 1/10 of the requirements @FakhruddinUjjainwala

Comment: You will figure out the solution ur self then as without the complete knowledge of the problem is difficult for me to assist you.